# Dart null safety complains about a function becoming null despite the null check being there

Tags: flutter, dart

So I have a following class which takes `onPressed` as a prop which can be null:

```
class Class1 {
  final Function? onPressed;
  
  const Class1({ this.onPressed });
  
  callMethod() {
    if(onPressed != null) {
      onPressed(); // Complains here
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see I have a check if `onPressed` is null. But dart still complains with this message `The function can't be unconditionally invoked because it can be 'null'. (view docs) Try adding a null check ('!').` Please help me.

Comment: Note that in your case, you could just remove the `if` statement and use `onPressed?.call();`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding a null check ('!') as compiler suggests

```
class Class1 {
  final Function? onPressed;

  const Class1({this.onPressed});

  callMethod() {
    if (onPressed != null) {
      onPressed!(); //Note: ! is added here
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if we do this, when press wouldnt it throws "Null check operator used on a null value
"?

Comment: In this case we have a check at runtime "if (onPressed != null)", so it is not possible to get "Null check" exception here